# Providing an alternative jupiter engine implementation or is jupiter-api special

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

For some reasons, I'd like to play around with an alternative implementation for the jupiter-engine.

Now, for some reason I have the impression that at least IntelliJ  automatically adds the default jupiter-engine to the test execution class path even though if I only added the jupiter-api (in gradle).

I'd expect that, if I don't add an engine manually to the class path, I just should NOT have an engine.

Is this true? Is this by-design? Or am I plain wrong?

Comment: Do you "extend JupiterTestEngine" directly? Do you provide an alternate implementation via "implements TestEngine" and use the same engine ID?

Comment: No, i provide my own engine ID but re-use some of the classes. So i could yes, what i think might happen is that  the launcher api sees both descriptors in the jars). As a solution I can repackage/shadow the original engine implementation.

Comment: But.. what my real concern is that.. the IDE loads the default jupiter-engine when you add the jupiter-api to the class path. And this default behaviour is, what concerns me. For the gradle/maven plugins i know you can select/include/exclude engines by id. No problem with that.

Comment: That might be hard-coded into IDEA -- perhaps a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=%23%7BUnit%20Testing.%20JUnit%7D%20 can shed light on this.

Comment: Follow up to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179398 -- thanks for creating the issue.